# From shell, is there a Java tool to check which compiled .class file(s) have a main method?

Tags: java, shell, program-entry-point

I'm putting together some (Python) scripts to help me automate some of my grading of hundreds of simple student Java repos. Not all of them have the same directory structure or naming of files. I've traversed them all and compiled them and if I make assumptions I can run them and test them, etc. But I'd like to know if there's a way I could find the "main" .class that has the `main()` method in it, so that I don't have to make assumptions about their file naming (which wouldn't work all the time anyway).

I'm aware of reflection, so yes, I know I could write another simple helper Java program to assist me in identifying it myself. But I was wondering if anything already exists (`java` command line option, tool from the jdk, etc.) to test a .class file to see if it is has the `main()` method in it.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128533/java-list-all-methods-and-classes-in-a-jar-file-of-specific-package-using-cmd/42128571) similar question seems to come to the same conclusion (reflection or extraction of the .class files and use of ```javap```)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if anything already exists (java command line option, tool from the JDK, etc.) to test a .class file to see if it is has the main() method in it.

There is no tool or option in Java SE that does that directly.

> I know I could write another simple helper Java program to assist me ...

It would be simpler to write a shell script that iterates a file tree, finds `.class` files, calls `javap` on them, and greps for a method with the appropriate `main` method signature.

Or you could do something similar on the source code tree.

---

(In retrospect, you should have set the assignment requirements so that the students had to use a specified class and package name for the class containing their main method.  But it is too late for that now ...)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Yes, I've taught for 7 years so I'm aware how to adjust assignments. For CS1 students I keep them on rails. For other classes, I let them organize how they see fit. I've written auto-graders before too in other languages. I'm not stressing about this, just checking to see if there are existing tools...

Comment: Although I'm not crazy about this solution, it seems to be the consensus. As some have mentioned, there could be multiple entry points too, so really "an investigation" is needed to find them.

Answer (score 1):

In the C++ days, distributing the headers files to use a shared object file was a big deal.  People would get one or the other without both, and there was always the chance you'd get mis-matched versions.

Java fixed that with `javap` which prints the methods (and other major interfaces) of a compiled `.class` file.

To test if a class file has a main, run

```
javap SomeFile.class
```

which will list all public interfaces.  Within that list, see if it has the "main entry point"

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[])
```

Now to handle this in mass, simply create a Python script that:

1. Locates all the relevant classes.
2. Runs `javap` on the class.
3. Reads the output for a method that matches (at the beginning, as there can be a variable number of Exceptions at the end "public static void main(java.lang.String[])

And you'll find all entry points.

Keep in mind that sometimes a single library or JAR file has many entry points, some of which are not intended as the primary entry point.

Answer (score 0):

Well simply calling `java -cp . <file>` will either completely blow out if the class doesn't have a `main` method or will run the relevant code. Now, if the code fails to run right and errors out you may see it as the same effect as not having a `main` method.

```
public class HasMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hit main");
    }
}
public class HasDoIt {
    public static void doIt(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hit doIt");
    }
}
public class WillBlowUp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hit blowUp");
        throw new IllegalStateException("oops");
    }
}
```

Using PowerShell:

```
PS D:\Development\sandbox> javac HasMain.java
PS D:\Development\sandbox> javac HasDoIt.java
PS D:\Development\sandbox> javac WillBlowUp.java

PS D:\Development\sandbox> java -cp . HasMain                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Hit main

PS D:\Development\sandbox> $?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
True

PS D:\Development\sandbox> java -cp . HasDoIt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Error: Main method not found in class HasDoIt, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

PS D:\Development\sandbox> $?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
False

PS D:\Development\sandbox> java -cp . WillBlowUp                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Hit blowUp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: oops
    at WillBlowUp.main(WillBlowUp.java:4)

PS D:\Development\sandbox> $?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
False
```

So simply checking return values could be a quick way to test if the class has what you want, albeit any exit(1) type return will throw a false-false

Comment: This doesn't **find** the file that contains the `main` method.  It tests class that you presumably have already found.  (And it is theoretically dangerous too; e.g. if the student has included a stealthy second "main" class that quietly does something nasty to the machine running the code.  Though, that is a problem no matter what ...)